# collectionView's didSelectItemAtIndexPath not working [Swift]

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I've been having this problem recently, and I couldn't seem to find a fix on any other similar questions. I have a collectionView which just display's colours (see below image) and I would like to store the cell's background colour in a variable to pass through an unwind segue, in order to set a background colour of another element. However, I can't seem to get this function to work as it has on previous projects and versions of this application and I was wondering if anyone knows what the problem might be ?

[image: CollectionView]

After pressing the 'add' button at the bottom, it unwinds and appends a new item to another collectionView, seen here:

[image: Other]

I am able to get the name that the user has put in, however I have to use a default colour as I can't seem to get the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` function to work.

Here's my code for the addViewController (first image)

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework

class mondayViewController: UIViewController {

    // collectionView
    @IBOutlet var dayView: UICollectionView!

    // data to display
    var data = Day.mondayData()

    // data from segues
    var receivedName: String?
    var receivedColour: UIColor?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set title
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Monday"
        // set datasource for collectionView 
        // datasource is self as the collectionViewDataSource methods are in the extension class below
        dayView.dataSource = self

        // make the navigationBar flat to flow onto the options tab
        self.navigationController?.hidesNavigationBarHairline = true


    }

    @IBAction func unwindToMonday(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {


        if segue.identifier == "mondayUnwind" {

            let subjectAdd = segue.sourceViewController as! mondayAddSubjectView

            receivedName = subjectAdd.nameField.text

            appendStuff()
        }




    }

    func appendStuff() {



        data.append(Day(name: receivedName, color: UIColor.flatRedColor()))
        dayView.reloadData()


    }

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }



//    data.append(Day(name: receivedName, color: receivedColour))
//    dayView.reloadData()


    // currently used for testing
    @IBAction func mondayAddButton(sender: AnyObject) {}


}


// mandatory functions for UICollectionView to work
// this includes assigning the number of sections, how manycells are meant to be in the section(s) and what cell to use (mondayCell in this case)

extension mondayViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return data.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! mondayCell
        cell.data = self.data[indexPath.item]


        return cell
    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    }



    // custom style the size of the collectionView. Changes the width to fill the screen and the height to 70

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                               sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let kWhateverHeightYouWant = 80
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, CGFloat(kWhateverHeightYouWant))
    }




}
```

if anyone could let me know if I am doing something wrong, or if there is a solution to this issue, that would be awesome.

Cheers,

Rowan

UPDATE:

I have added the collectionViewDataSource and Delegate Methods to the main class (code below):

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework


class mondayAddSubjectView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var pageView: PageViewController = PageViewController()



    @IBOutlet var selectColourLabel: UILabel!
    // would be a public variable, however it is an internal class
    internal var cellColour: UIColor!

    // collectionView
    @IBOutlet var colourPicker: UICollectionView!


    // textfield for the user to input their subject name
    @IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!

    // source of colours to use in the colour collectionView
    private var data = collectionViewColors.createColor()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.colourPicker.delegate = self


        colourPicker.dataSource = self
        // gesture recognizer to determine when the user has tapped anywhere but the text field, which cancells the keyboard

        let tap: UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mondayAddSubjectView.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    }

    // dismiss keyboard when the user taps away from the text field (called above with #selector)
    func dismissKeyboard() {

        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    // MARK: - CollectionView Delegate and Data source methods


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)



        print("it works")

    }

    // choose how many sections are in the collectionView. as no content break is required, this will be 1
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    // choose how many items are in each section. as there is only 1 section, it will be the number of stored items
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return data.count
    }
    // set re-use identifier and the data that will go in each cell
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colourCell
        cell.data = self.data[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }







}
```

Comment: get data by `self.data[indexPath.item]` in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` func and store it with member variables

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to work though, as the function still isn't getting called

Comment: Have you added the Collection View Delegate?

Comment: @VictorRius I have set the collectionView delegate to self via the storyboard

Comment: yeah that's right, but same as you did with the loading functions within the DataSource extension it has also to be done with the Delegate for the didSelectItemAtIndexPath func. "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" is a delegate func not DataSource

Comment: @VictorRius It still doesn't seem to work, do you have a code sample that would show how you do it ? Thanks for the help

Comment: sure bro. Download this project (I finished it yesterday). https://gitlab.com/vicrius/flickrVisualizer .

In the Home View Controller if you delete the "UICollectionViewDelegate" at the top and comment the 'self.collectionView.delegate = self" you will see that the 'didSelectItemAtIndexPath' doesn't work anymore. 

You are doing the same but from an extension. Move the 'didSelect' to the main class and set there after the UIViewController type the UICollectionViewDelegate as I have

Comment: @VictorRius Cheers, i'll have a look

Comment: The easiest way will be to move the whole extension code into de main class and set next to the class type the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and the `UICollectionViewDelegate`

Comment: @VictorRius I've had a look at your code, however when I try to replicate what you have done, which was move the datasource methods into the main class, it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: can I see your whole project somewhere please? After moving the methods to the main class have you added the UICollectionViewDelegate?

Comment: Yeah sure, i'll add an update to the question, and yes I believe that I have added the delegate

Comment: Thanks, just saw it. Looks fine to me... only think left to be added by code would be the `self.colourPicker.delegate = self` below the dataSource. Try it even having done it in the Storyboard. If it's not that I have no more ideas.

Comment: @VictorRius still doesn't seem to work, thanks heaps for your help though, you have certainly made the code cleaner now that I no longer need all of the extensions !

Comment: You're welcome mate, did my best! Is there any way I can get into this code and test it myself? I'm junior so this things are perfect for me to learn.

Comment: @VictorRius at the moment, no, my github is locked on a private repository at the moment, as it is controlled by school because this is a major project. I wish I could share my code though. Sorry !

Comment: I had a similar problem and for me the reason was that I had a button covering the entire cell and so whenever I tapped on the cell, it was the button's selector that was being called. Depending on the type of view you're adding to your cell, it might be a similar issue. I solved mine by replacing the button with a label. Although, another possible solution might be to decrease the amount of space the child view of the cell is taking up.